# May I please set a bounty on more than one question?

Tags: feature-request, bounties, active-bounties

I have three questions on Stack Overflow that I want to offer bounties on. Trouble is, I already have an outstanding bounty on another question, and thus I can't offer bounties on any other questions until I award that one (and even then I'll be limited to one at a time). I respectfully disagree with the FAQ's guidance that only one bounty may be offered per user, and request that the limit be increased.